# How to get a layout Trace in a Swift Playground

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift-playground

Im prototyping some Views in a Swift Playground.

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: CGSize(width: 320, height: 300)))

XCPShowView("Container View", containerView)
```

I am using this Container View to throw in some Views and Layout them with Constraints. 
Now i would really like to get a LayoutTrace from it, like the one from

```
po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]
```

This would allow me to easily find some Ambiguous Layout.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Objective-C runtime's `valueForKey` to access `_autolayoutTrace` from a Swift Playground:

```
print(containerView.valueForKey("_autolayoutTrace"))
```